# Displacement of an element under floated element

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain why the element below the floated element gets displaced as if it had a padding of a width of the floated element?

HTML and CSS:

```css
        div.filter { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; padding: 0 10px 10px 10px; width: 300px;}
        div.filterTitle { float:left; padding: 5px; margin:-12px 0 0 10px; background:#fff; }
        div.filter label { display:inline-block; width: 120px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 15px;}
        div.filter input[type="text"] { width: 146px; }
```

```html
<div class="filter">
<div class="filterTitle">Filters</div>
<form id="filterForm" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label for="dateFrom" class="optional">Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom" value="">
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

FIDDLE: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mtkfuya/)

Comment: Can you please explain what is the expected behaviour you want? it seems to be OK on Chrome

Comment: You should probably be using the `legend` element here ...might make things easier.

Comment: Both elements should be displayed on one line, the label should be positioned right at the left border with 10px padding as described in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you are asking but based on comments I think this is just a case of clearing the float.

```css
/* filters menu */
 div.filter {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
div.filterTitle {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:-12px 0 0 10px;
    background:#fff;
}
form {
    clear: both;
}
div.filter label {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
div.filter input[type="text"] {
    width: 146px;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
    <div class="filterTitle">Filters</div>
    <form id="filterForm" method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="dateFrom" class="optional">Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom" value=""/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

You might also want to look into the `fieldset` and `legend` elements which would seem to be more inline with the look you seem to be aiming for.

[**Fieldset @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

[**Quick JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pu9p7e4k/)

Comment: There will be more elements on the page that mimic the `fieldset/legend` look, that are not forms. Not sure if it would be correct to use it in all cases.